# tensorflow.keras model accuracy, loss, and validation metrics remain static during 30 epochs of training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have written a CNN that takes in MFCC spectrograms and is meant to classify the images into five different classes. I trained the model for 30 epochs and after the first epoch, no metrics change. Could it be a problem with imbalanced classification, and if so, how would I bias the model for the dataset, if possible? Below is the data generator code, the model definition, and the outputs. The original model had two additional layers however, I started tweaking things when I was trying to troubleshoot the issue

Data Generator Definition:

```
path = 'path_to_dataset'
CLASS_NAMES = ['belly_pain', 'burping', 'discomfort', 'hungry', 'tired']
CLASS_NAMES = np.array(CLASS_NAMES)
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150
# 457 is the number of images total
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(457/BATCH_SIZE)

img_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2, horizontal_flip=True, rotation_range=45, width_shift_range=.15, height_shift_range=.15)

train_data_gen = img_generator.flow_from_directory( directory=path, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), classes = list(CLASS_NAMES), subset='training', class_mode='categorical')

validation_data_gen = img_generator.flow_from_directory( directory=path, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), classes = list(CLASS_NAMES), subset='validation', class_mode='categorical')
```

Model Definition:

```
EPOCHS = 30

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', 
           input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='sigmoid'),
    Dense(1)
])

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

First 5 Epochs:

```
Epoch 1/30
368/368 [==============================] - 371s 1s/step - loss: 0.6713 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 2/30
368/368 [==============================] - 235s 640ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 3/30
368/368 [==============================] - 233s 633ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 4/30
368/368 [==============================] - 236s 641ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 5/30
368/368 [==============================] - 234s 636ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
```

Last Five Epochs:

```
Epoch 25/30
368/368 [==============================] - 231s 628ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 26/30
368/368 [==============================] - 227s 617ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 27/30
368/368 [==============================] - 228s 620ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 28/30
368/368 [==============================] - 234s 636ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 29/30
368/368 [==============================] - 235s 638ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 30/30
368/368 [==============================] - 234s 636ms/step - loss: 0.5004 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5004 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
```

Comment: Please do not use the comments space to offer such updates in your own question - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to achieve a classification task with 4 classes but your last layer only contain one neuron.

It should be a dense layer with 4 neurons and a softmax activation :

`Dense(4, activation="softmax")`

You need to also change the loss function accordingly to classification loss like for example `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: The loss should also be changed in such a case; please update your answer accordingly.

Comment: Would I be able to just use CCE with no params or do I pass in the datagenerator objects to that function?

Comment: I'm not sure to perfectly understand your question but you don't need give any arguments, in your case, you just have to change the loss argument in the `model.compile` method.